Koin in Kotlin multiplatform (kmp) desktop platform error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/koin/core/error/KoinAppAlreadyStartedException
I am using Kotlin multiplatform (KMP) compose to develop app. After adding koin I am able to run on Android, iOS and Web but when run for desktop platform it shows an error immediately after running.
Error in UI looks like below:

IDE: Android studio.
Run command to run for desktop: ./gradlew :composeApp:run
Error log from logcat:
> Task :composeApp:run
2024-08-02 05:21:45.947 java[1103:11876] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing 
NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/koin/core/error/KoinAppAlreadyStartedException
    at AppKt.App(App.kt:29)

---
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.koin.core.error.KoinAppAlreadyStartedException

Using below library versions for commonMain dependencies:
koin = "4.0.0-RC1"
koin-compose = "1.2.0-Beta4"

koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-compose", version.ref = "koin-compose" 

Koin initialisation like below:
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    KoinApplication(application = { // Exception log referring this line (29 no line in App.kt file)
        modules(appModule, platformModule)
    }) {
        MaterialTheme {
       ...

This error only throwing in desktop(JVM) platform.

Are you using koinViewModel() to inject in a KMP Project? If so, I am facing the same issue here. Did you find any solutions to this yet?

@andre got the solution, please follow the accepted answer. Use of same version "4.0.0-RC1" fix the problem.

I found our problem.
Which is incorrect versioning of koin-compose on our side.
Since koin version 4.0.0-RC1, koin-compose has the same version number.
Which means you just need to do:
koin = "4.0.0-RC1"

koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-compose", version.ref = "koin"  }

Hope this helped!

I Don't have access to code but As I know the issue is due to starting multiple Koin. There are two way to start the Koin.
First way:
 startKoin {
        // Log Koin into Android logger
        androidLogger()
        // Reference Android context
        androidContext(this@MainApplication)
        // Load modules
        modules(myAppModules)
    }

And the other way is By using Koin Application:
KoinApplication(application = {
    // your preview config here
    modules(previewModule)
}) {
    // Compose to preview with Koin
}

Don't use both together. If you do then, you will get this type of error

I used only 2nd option. Other platforms are working fine but only desktop showing error.

Please share your dependency as well as build.gradle.kts file. You might be missing something.

If it wouldn't be the specific versions of koin and koin-compose mentioned above, this answer would be the correct one.
